# Why is background-image not working for Input?

Tags: html, css, input, background-image

I have set my image input to a submit input with background-image:

```html
<input title="Search" class="searchButton" id="searchButton" type="submit" style="background-image: url(/cdn/png/search.png); height: 34px; width: 34px;" value="">
```

But then it just shows as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khaGj.png)

Please tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `background-size`, `background-repeat`, and `background-position`.

```css
.searchButton {
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  
  background-color: black;
  border: 0px;

  background-image: url(https://dinblox.org/cdn/png/search.png);
  background-size: 28px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<input title="Search" class="searchButton" id="searchButton" type="submit" value="">
```

Or the inline CSS:

```
<input title="Search" class="searchButton" id="searchButton" type="submit" value="" style="width:34px;height:34px;background-image: url(https://dinblox.org/cdn/png/search.png);background-size: 28px;background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
```

Comment: That seemed to work, thanks.
Though I have to add it as style="css" and cannot use my class for it, any solution to that too?

Comment: Thanks, will use and mark as answer. Can I have the Image 3px away from the borders though? My way to do that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DindinYT37, Yup look at my edit. Basically just set the size to 28px (34 - 6). Since you decrease its size to less than 100%, multiple instances can show. You'll have to use `background-repeat: no-repeat` to stop it.